# Book The Art of PostgreSQL self study don't understand lateral join mean?

Tags: postgresql

I guess in this tag many people bought the book "The Art of PostgreSQL".  The book content is the context for this question. I self-paced learning from this book. I encountered some problems, so I write a mail to the author, also ask this question in here.

On page 47:

- I Totally don't understand what does line 27 `limit :n` mean?
- I also don't know what does line 34 `ss(name, albumid, count) on true` mean?
- I kind of get some part of it. But I am still not sure what does
  LATERAL JOIN DO?

  ```
  -- name: genre-top-n
   2 -- Get the N top tracks by genre
   3 select genre.name as genre,
   4 case when length(ss.name) > 15
   5 then substring(ss.name from 1 for 15) || '…'
   6 else ss.name
   7 end as track,
   8 artist.name as artist
   9 from genre
   10 left join lateral
   11 /*
   12 * the lateral left join implements a nested loop over
   13 * the genres and allows to fetch our Top-N tracks per
   Chapter 5 A Small Application | 47
   14 * genre, applying the order by desc limit n clause.
   15 *
   16 * here we choose to weight the tracks by how many
   17 * times they appear in a playlist, so we join against
   18 * the playlisttrack table and count appearances.
   19 */
   20 (
   21 select track.name, track.albumid, count(playlistid)
   22 from track
   23 left join playlisttrack using (trackid)
   24 where track.genreid = genre.genreid
   25 group by track.trackid
   26 order by count desc
   27 limit :n
   28 )
   29 /*
   30 * the join happens in the subquery's where clause, so
   31 * we don't need to add another one at the outer join
   32 * level, hence the "on true" spelling.
   33 */
   34 ss(name, albumid, count) on true
   35 join album using(albumid)
   36 join artist using(artistid)
   37 order by genre.name, ss.count desc;
  ```

Comment: Please *don’t* assume that anyone has any particular book at hand and keep your question self contained for anyone to answer.

Comment: Line 34 is a table alias: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES